# Stop handler autorun when float hits zero

Tags: java, android, handler

Basically I have a handler which will auto run for a certain period. Here is the code:

```
long time = 0;
for (int iii = 0; iii < GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.directionList.size(); iii++) {
    final int counter = iii;
    time += 1000;
    EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

            EventMain.tvDirection.setText(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.directionList.get(counter));

            float timeLeft = Float.parseFloat(EventMain.tvTimeLeft.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.timeLeftList.get(counter));
            EventMain.tvTimeLeft.setText(String.valueOf(timeLeft));

            float distanceLeft = Float.parseFloat(EventMain.tvDistLeft.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.distLeftList.get(counter));
            EventMain.tvDistLeft.setText(String.valueOf(distanceLeft));
        }
    }, time);
}
```

With these code, the handler will keep run all the way until my float become negative value. So I wonder how it should be modified so that either one of the float hits zero, then the handler will stop running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got lost to this line `EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);`. Can't understand why you need it

Comment: I thought that line will postDelayed the first item to loop for 5000 miliseconds?

Comment: more ore less. In your case will schedule **another**  execution of `this` runnable after 5 seconds. And it is gonna happen *forever* if you don't clean up the handler's queue

Comment: So basically is that line causing the problem?

Comment: *So basically is that line causing the problem?*,  probably yes, but I am not sure about that. It is making leaking your activity for sure

Comment: I see, you were correct. Would you mind to post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is due of

```
  EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
```

that  will schedule **another** execution of `this` runnable after 5 seconds. And it is gonna happen *forever* if you don't clean up the handler's queue. Also, this way you'll leak the `Activity`